# Fast reading contacts android

Tags: android, android-contacts

Is there a faster method for reading contacts in android? For example my method with cursor take 3-5 seconds for reading 30-50 contacts. It's very long.

```
        Cursor cursor =  managedQuery(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);      
           while (cursor.moveToNext()) 
           {           
               String contactId = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));

               String hasPhone = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER));

               if ( hasPhone.equalsIgnoreCase("1"))
                   hasPhone = "true";
               else
                   hasPhone = "false" ;

               if (Boolean.parseBoolean(hasPhone)) 
               {
                Cursor phones = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null,ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID +" = "+ contactId,null, null);
                while (phones.moveToNext()) 
                {
                  names.add(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME))); 
                  numbers.add(phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER)));
                }
                phones.close();
               }
          }
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

your question is interesting....

reading a fast contacts because it take time to read contacts data from ContactsContract..

i don't know about another way then the one you use, but still u can increase the performance by providing a String[] projection parameter to managedQuery...

fetch only those data which u require from contactsContract, because by providing null value it fetches all the columns of the record.

Comment: I agree with this answer. Also, you should use [CursorLoader](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/CursorLoader.html) as it will do the work off the UI thread (if you aren't doing that already).

Answer (score 2):

Sorry for my bad english. I have created the similar but with different style using HashMap. I will paste my approach.

```
            //Create a hashMap, Key => Raw Contact ID and value => Object of customClass

            HashMap<Long, ContactStructure> mFinalHashMap = new HashMap<Long, ContactStructure>();

            //Run IN query in data table. example

             select mimetype_id, raw_contact_id, data1 to data14 from data where raw_contact_id IN (select _id from raw_contacts where deleted <> 1 and account_type = "phone" and account_name = "bla bla") and mimetype_id = (select _id from mimetypes where mimetype = "vnd.something.phone");
```

Now Create a class which will have all the data of contact.

while accessing the cursor.

```
            while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
                ContactStructure contactStructure = mFinalHashMap.get(rawContactID);
        //It will return the previous instance of object, If we already put
                    if(rawContactStructure == null) {
                        contactStructure = ContactStructure.provideInstance();
                    }

    //Now check for your required mimeType
                           case MIMETYPE_PHONE:
                    contactStructure.hasPhoneNo = true;
                    contactStructure.phoneNumbers.add(addDetail); //add the data1 .. to data14
                break;

            }

    /*Demo class for saving the details*/
    public class ContactMetaData {
        static classContactStructure {
                   boolean          hasPhoneNo;
            List<List<String>>  phoneNumbers; 
    public static ContactStructure provideInstance() {
contact.phoneNumbers = new ArrayList<List<String>>();
            ContactStructure contact = new RawContactStructure();
return contact
    }

    }
```

use this approach, I tried with 3000 contacts with all the data, It was fast. coz its not easy to get all the contacts and their all data with in sec..